# c pthread_create string argument

Tags: c, string, arguments, pthreads

I using c thread.

I want to using string argument.

in my source

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  pthread_t thread[1];
  pthread_create(&thread[0], NULL, thread_A, (void *) argv[0]);
  pthread_join(thread[0], NULL)
}

void * thread_A(void * arg){
  char argv[100] = {0};
  strcpy(argv, (char *) arg);
}
```

when comfile this
warning like this

> pthread.h:225:12: note: expected 'void * (*)(void *)' but argument is of type 'void * (*)(char **)'

so I use (void *)&argv[0]. but this is error too.

what can I try?

Comment: The warning is talking about the third argument, the function pointer, it seems that `thread_A` is in reality a `void *thread_A(char **data)`. It has nothing to do with the forth parameter.

Comment: I use this, but warning... thank you answer

Answer (score 4):

Doing

```
pthread_create(&thread[0], NULL, thread_A, (void *) argv[0]);
```

and even without the cast

```
pthread_create(&thread[0], NULL, thread_A, argv[0]);
```

would be perfectly fine if you want to pass a string as an argument. But the
warning you are seeing

> pthread.h:225:12: note: expected `void * (*)(void *)` but argument is of type `void * (*)(char **)`

is not talking about the forth parameter (the argument to the thread function), it's about the third parameter: the
function pointer. In this case is says that the function you are passing has
this signature:

```
void *thread_A(char **arg);
```

when it's expecting a

```
void *thread_A(void *arg);
```

The code you posted doesn't generate the warning you've posted and I assume that the code you
are really using declares `thread_A` as a `void * (*)(char **)` and not as `void * (*)(void*)`. So check
you code carefully.

So the real cast you are looking for would be

```
pthread_create(&thread[0], NULL, (void * (*)(void*)) thread_A, argv[0]);
```

Comment: I got solving problem using you answer thank for you help.